# Mi actualización no llega correctamente a los usuarios / Google Play

Tags: android, google-play-console, store

Buen día, tengo un problema con actualizar mi aplicación en **Google Play** sucede que desde hace tiempo las actualizaciones no llegan de forma correcta a los usuarios mi aplicación es una prueba abierta (acceso anticipado) y cada vez que la quiero actualizar tengo problemas al tratar de actualizar, comúnmente una aplicación promedio debería actualizarse automáticamente (Si tiene marcada la opción de actualizaciones automáticas claro) pero en mi caso no lo hace, hay ocasiones en las que debo ingresar a la **Play Store** para poder actualizar le doy actualizar y no actualiza o la abre de una vez hay ocasiones en las que debo incluso entrar a los detalles de la versión para que se vea reflejada la actualización (lo cual es demasiado extraño) entonces tengo muchas preguntas que es que estoy haciendo mal? es porque es una prueba abierta y no en producción? el problema es la **Play Store** o la **Google Play Console**? me falta configurar algo?

A continuación mostrare el proceso que hago para usa subida de la actualización:

En primer lugar lo que tengo que hacer es subir la el **versionCode** y el **versionName**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Luego en **Generated signed Bundle / APK** selecciono la primer opción

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En esta parte cabe aclarar que cuando elijo `debug` me dice que la versión no esta firmada por eso tengo elegida la versión de `release`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y por ultimo pues lo de siempre solo elijo **Editar Versión** y subo el archivo `.aab`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y eso seria todo el proceso sinceramente no se que mas se debe configurar o hacer para que la aplicación se suba y llegue correctamente a los usuarios espero que alguien con experiencia en este tema de subidas me pueda instruir de antemano muchas gracias!

Comment: Has probado usar en la configuracion solo... versionCode 48
versionName "1.5.7" ?

Comment: Hola @LilibethQ no, eso solo era un ejemplo (por eso el error) del cambio no es que sea un error en realidad queda como lo mencionas en el primer comentario pero gracias por la respuesta!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> En primer lugar lo que tengo que hacer es subir la el versionCode y el
> versionName

El `versionCode` es muy importante ya que indica la versiòn del .apl, el `versionName` es simplemente un indicador de texto, de hecho puedes escribir cualquier texto y no influye en el poder subir o no tu aplicaciòn.

La razòn por la cual la actualización no llega correctamente a los usuarios es precisamente lo que comentas

> es porque es una prueba abierta y no en producción?

Si realizaste una prueba abierta, **la actualizaciòn la pueden recibir todos los usuarios, pero estos deben registrarse como [tester beta](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6307673?hl=es) o que ellos reciban en enlace de la aplicaciòn de prueba** que serìa:

[https://play.google.com/apps/testing/[package](https://play.google.com/apps/testing/%5Bpackage) name]

**Si deseas que a los usuarios que tengan configurada la actualización automática reciban esta actualización debes publicarla a producción.**

Comment: Hola, te agradezco tu respuesta, en el caso de que existan ocasiones las cuales si se actualice correctamente la aplicación sin hacer absolutamente nada y en ocasiones no lo haga se consideraría un error por parte de la play store o google play console? me explico como mencionaba en la pregunta es muy extraño porque a pesar de ser una prueba abierta haciendo pruebas con mi teléfono la aplicación si se actualizaba correctamente pero en ocasiones no y tenia que hacer lo que menciono en la pregunta, aunque aun no he testeado la aplicacion al 100% siento que tengo serios problemas de subida. salud

Comment: Si no esta publicada en producción y esta publicada para testing, únicamente la recibirán los usuarios que se encuentren suscritos a !beta testing para tu aplicación.

Comment: Bueno agradezco mucho tu respuesta, ya la publique en producción como me lo mencionas, saludos.